# Symfony 6 JWT with lexikjwtauthbundle /api/login_check request return 404 on localhost

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle, symfony6

I am trying JWT bundle lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle for authentication on localhost.
It is new project in symfony 6.

I am trying call the route via curl but I have got 404 error Not found.

I follow the instructions:
https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/doc/index.md

But the command **php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair** return this error
"error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process"

so I create keys manually:

**openssl genrsa -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256**

**openssl rsa -pubout -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem**

I have got error
Unable to find the controller for path "/api/login_check". The route is wrongly configured.

So I should have create own Controller ? Because it was not necessary in tutorials.

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        #main:
            #lazy: true
            #provider: users_in_memory
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon



routes.yaml


controllers:
    resource: ../src/Controller/
    type: annotation

kernel:
    resource: ../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation

api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

Comment: Have you got this in your `config/routes.yaml` : `api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check`

Comment: @jean-max Yes I have.

Comment: Did you see your route when you check this : `php bin/console debug:router` ?

Comment: @jean-max yes  api_login_check            ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/login_check Should have I create own Controller for thid method ? Because In debug mode I hav got "Unable to find the controller for path "/api/login_check". The route is wrongly configured."

Comment: Try to remove and reinstall JWT, and try to generate your keys only with JWT